# SQL - how to create a dynamic matrix showing attribution values per item over time (where number of attributes varies per date)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot, dynamic-pivot

**I have:**

`items` which are described by a set of ids (GroupType, ID, Name)

`VALUES` table which gets populated with factor values on each date so that an item gets only a certain set of factors with values per date.

`FACTORS` table containing static descriptions of the factors.

**Looking for:**


**I want to create a temporary table with a matrix showing factor values for each item per date** so that one could see in user friendly way which Factors were populated on a given date (with corresponding values).

Values

```
Date        GroupType   ID  Name   FactorId  Value
01/01/2013        1     1   A      1         10
01/01/2013        1     1   A      2         8
01/01/2013        1     1   A      3         12

01/01/2013        1     2   B      3         5
01/01/2013        1     2   B      4         6

02/01/2013        1     1   A      1         7
02/01/2013        1     1   A      2         6

02/01/2013        1     2   B      3         9
02/01/2013        1     2   B      4         9
```

Factors

```
FactorId FactorName 
1     Factor1
2     Factor2
3     Factor3
4     Factor4
.     .
.     .
.     .
```

## temporary table    Factor Values Matrix

```
Date          Group       ID     Name  Factor1    Factor2      Factor3     Factor4  Factor...
01/01/2013        1        1        A       10          8           12
01/01/2013        1        2        B                                5           6

02/01/2013        1        1        A        7          6           
02/01/2013        1        2        B                                9           9
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you could share your schema or create a sqlfiddle, that will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Damn tabs ... ... Hope it's correct now .

Comment: Which platform? does it support `PIVOT` ?

Comment: It is on  Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: I am doing something like this but it is not dynamic, I hardcode the self joins, every time I want to run a query I have to check available set of factors for a given date range and  adjust the self joins accordingly.

Comment: SELECT V.Date,V.Group,V.ID,V.Name,V1.Value as Factor1,V2.Value as Factor2,V3.Value as Factor3,V4.Value as Factor4
FROM Values V
LEFT JOIN 
Values V1 on V.GroupType = V1.GroupType and V.ID=V1.ID  and V.Date = V1.Date and FactorId = 1
LEFT JOIN 
Values V2 on V.GroupType = V2.GroupType and V.ID=V2.ID  and V.Date = V2.Date and FactorId = 2

LEFT JOIN 
Values V3 on V.GroupType = V3.GroupType and V.ID=V3.ID  and V.Date = V3.Date and FactorId = 3
LEFT JOIN 
Values V4 on V.GroupType = V4.GroupType and V.ID=V4.ID  and V.Date = V4.Date and FactorId = 4
WHERE 
grouptype = 1  and date between "x" and "y"

Comment: @Michal . . . Why are you using self-joins?  Did you see my response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of data transformation is known as a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which takes values from rows and converts it into columns.

In SQL Server 2005+, there is a function that will perform this rotation of data.

**Static Pivot:**

If your values will be set then you can hard-code the `FactorNames` into the columns by using a static pivot.

```
select date, grouptype, id, name, Factor1, Factor2, Factor3, Factor4
from
(
  select v.date,
    v.grouptype,
    v.id,
    v.name,
    f.factorname,
    v.value
  from [values] v
  left join factors f 
    on v.factorid = f.factorid
  -- where v.date between date1 and date2
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for factorname in (Factor1, Factor2, Factor3, Factor4)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1132/2).

**Dynamic Pivot:**

In your case, you stated that you are going to have an unknown number of values.  If so, then you will need to use dynamic SQL to generate a SQL string that will be executed at run-time:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(FactorName) 
                    from factors
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT date, grouptype, id, name,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select v.date,
                  v.grouptype,
                  v.id,
                  v.name,
                  f.factorname,
                  v.value
                from [values] v
                left join factors f 
                  on v.factorid = f.factorid
                -- where v.date between date1 and date2
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for factorname in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1132/1).

Both of these versions generate the same result:

```
|       DATE | GROUPTYPE | ID | NAME | FACTOR1 | FACTOR2 | FACTOR3 | FACTOR4 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2013-01-01 |         1 |  1 |    A |      10 |       8 |      12 |  (null) |
| 2013-01-01 |         1 |  2 |    B |  (null) |  (null) |       5 |       6 |
| 2013-02-01 |         1 |  1 |    A |       7 |       6 |      11 |  (null) |
| 2013-02-01 |         1 |  1 |    B |  (null) |  (null) |       9 |       9 |
```

If you want to filter the results based on a date range, then you will just need to add a `WHERE` clause to the above queries.

Comment: @Michal Does this answer solve your problem?  I see that you commented as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are simply trying to pivot the rows into columns.  I think this does what you want:

```
select Date, Group, ID, Name, 
       max(case when factorid = 1 then name end) as Factor1,
       max(case when factorid = 2 then name end) as Factor2,
       max(case when factorid = 3 then name end) as Factor3,
       max(case when factorid = 4 then name end) as Factor4
from t
group by Date, Group, ID, Name
```